# Finding value of textbox in same row as clickable element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML table. In each row, I have a 'Add' button along with a quantity input box, the model #, model description and price. When that button is clicked I have an onclick event which fires off our Analytics Tracking function.

On the click of the add button, I need to get the quantity from the textbox from the same row that the 'ADD' button is clicked. Currently, the only element being returned is the first row of the table. I have tried several methods using .click, .live and .on as well as .closest.

Here is the code, I hope someone can help me as I am lost trying to get this value.

### HTML

```
<table id="ElementCount10">
    <thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="image">
                    <div class="modelphoto link"><a rel="#"><img class="modelthumb" alt="" src="image.jpg"></a></div>
                </td>
                <td class="model sorting_1">
                    <a class="sku" href="#">Sample Part</a>
                </td>
                <td class="descript" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Part Description</td>
                <td class="avail"><span class="instock">In Stock</span></td>
                <td class="price">$318.00</td>
                <td class="cart">
                    <input type="hidden" name="labelid" value="1234567">
                    <input type="hidden" name="productid" value="Part Number">
                    <input class="qty" type="text" name="quantity" value="" size="2" maxlength="3">
                    <a class="btn-primary" href="#" onclick="SiteCatalystSingleTracking('SingleAddToCart',1,this,event.target.nodeName);return false;">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <td class="image">
                    <div class="modelphoto link"><a rel="#"><img class="modelthumb" alt="" src="image.jpg"></a></div>
               </td>
               <td class="model sorting_1"><a class="sku" href="#">Part Number</a></td>
               <td class="descript" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Part Description</td>
               <td class="avail"><span class="instock">In Stock</span></td>
               <td class="price">$371.00</td>
               <td class="cart">
                   <input type="hidden" name="labelid" value="1234567">
                   <input type="hidden" name="productid" value="Part Number">
                   <input class="qty" type="text" name="quantity" value="" size="2" maxlength="3">
                   <a class="btn-primary" href="#" onclick="SiteCatalystSingleTracking('SingleAddToCart',1,this,event.target.nodeName);return false;">
               </td>
          </tr>
```

### JS

```
function SiteCatalystSingleTracking(carttype, requiredamt, $this, thisTarget) { // $this is the actual table to process
    var parts = '';
    var node = "";
    var parent_path = '';
    alert("T:" + thisTarget);
    thisNewTarget = $(thisTarget).parents("td.cart").children("input[name=quantity]").val();
    alert("NT: " + thisNewTarget);
    parent_path = $($this).parents("table").attr("id");
    var sku = $("#" + parent_path + " tbody tr .cart").children("input[name=productid]").val();
    var qty = $("#" + parent_path + " tbody tr .cart").children("input[name=quantity]").val();
    var labelid = $("#" + parent_path + " tbody tr .cart").children("input[name=labelid]").val();
 }
```

I really need some help on this. Anything would be great!

-HeatherBear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$($this).closest("tr").find("input[name=quantity]").val();
```

Though you really shouldn't name your parameter `$this` when it isn't a jquery object but rather a DOM element.  That can be really confusing.

Comment: Thanks James!  This worked for me. I realize you shouldn't mix jquery with DOM but I got handed this bag of worms and have to deal with it.

Comment: @HeatherRoberts You're welcome.  Though I wasn't saying don't mix, just naming convention.  Usually a variable named starting with a `$` means it's a jquery object.

Answer (score 1):

First, most people I know that do jQuery shutter to see events attached to DOM elements directly in the HTML, as you are doing here:

```
<a class="btn-primary" href="#" onclick="SiteCatalystSingleTracking('SingleAddToCart',1,this,event.target.nodeName);return false;">
```

I would highly recommend NOT doing that.

What I would recommend is something like this:

```
<table id="ElementCount10">
    <thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td class="image">
                    <div class="modelphoto link"><a rel="#"><img class="modelthumb" alt="" src="image.jpg"></a></div>
                </td>
                <td class="model sorting_1">
                    <a class="sku" href="#">Sample Part</a>
                </td>
                <td class="descript" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Part Description</td>
                <td class="avail"><span class="instock">In Stock</span></td>
                <td class="price">$318.00</td>
                <td class="cart">
                    <input type="hidden" name="labelid" value="1234567">
                    <input type="hidden" name="productid" value="Part Number">
                    <input class="qty" type="text" name="quantity" value="" size="2" maxlength="3">
                    <input type="button" value="Add" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even">
                <td class="image">
                    <div class="modelphoto link"><a rel="#"><img class="modelthumb" alt="" src="image.jpg"></a></div>
               </td>
               <td class="model sorting_1"><a class="sku" href="#">Part Number</a></td>
               <td class="descript" rowspan="1" colspan="1">Part Description</td>
               <td class="avail"><span class="instock">In Stock</span></td>
               <td class="price">$371.00</td>
               <td class="cart">
                   <input type="hidden" name="labelid" value="1234567">
                   <input type="hidden" name="productid" value="Part Number">
                   <input class="qty" type="text" name="quantity" value="" size="2" maxlength="3">
                   <input type="button" value="Add" />
               </td>
          </tr>
```

Then, in the JavaScript, I would do something like

```
<script>
  $().ready(function() {
    $('#ElementCount10').on('input:button','click',function(evt) {
      var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty)'.val();
      // Do you stuff with the value
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I would agree with you but unfortunately, at this time, I am unable to modify the code structure beyond what it is today.

Comment: So, you need to fix the code, but you can't modify the code?  What parts are you stuck with?

Comment: I'm stuck with the onclick event on the A tag and embedding the required JS code in the function that is called by the onclick event.

Comment: Also, #ElementCount10 is a dynamic value and not the same every time.

Comment: Ok, besides the implementation details of using the onclick, function, etc, the core is still the same:  You can get the value of the quantity using `var quantity = $(this).closest('tr').find('input.qty)'.val();`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-primary").click(function(){
        qty = $(this).parents('.cart').find('.qty').val();
        alert(qty);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `prev()` to get the previous input  like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".btn-primary").click(function(){
        alert($(this).prev('input[type=text].qs').val);
        });
    });
```